# maven-jaxb2-plugin forceRegenerate=false not working?

Tags: maven, configuration, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm trying to configure maven-jaxb2-plugin to only generate java if XSD changes.
That doesn't seem to work because java classes are always regenerated.
This is the plugin configuration :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</generateDirectory>
                <strict>true</strict>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <readOnly>true</readOnly>
                <episode>true</episode>
                <forceRegenerate>false</forceRegenerate>  
                <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>commun-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>my.package.dest</generatePackage>
                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/wsrest</schemaDirectory>
                        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/wsrest</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <include>bindings.xml</include>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <episodeFile>${basedir}/src/main/java/META-INF/sun-jaxb_commun.episode</episodeFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

When building (maven clean install or maven install) i can observe this output :

```
[INFO] File [D:\IDE\Data\Eclipse\workspace\MyProject\src\main\resources\schemas\wsrest\myXSD.xsd] was changed since the last build.
[INFO] File [D:\IDE\Data\Eclipse\workspace\MyProject\src\main\resources\schemas\wsrest\bindings.xml] was changed since the last build. 
[INFO] File [D:\IDE\Data\Eclipse\workspace\MyProject\pom.xml] was changed since the last build.
```

But i didn't change anything in theses files since the last build!

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Clément

Answer (score 1):

As a partial workaround you can add `<noFileHeader>true</noFileHeader>` to your configuration so that generated sources are the same for unchanged XSD. Solves my problems with repository commits, if that matters to you as well...

Can't stop XJC from re-generation it checks just timestamps it seems.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to stop regenerate because of the following:
I'd the same issue and I dug through the plugin code to find out the root cause:

The up-to-date check in `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.isUpToDate` uses `if (getBuildContext().hasDelta(dependsFile))` which delegates to `org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental.DefaultBuildContext.hasDelta` which is hard-coded to return true. This is because the concept of incremental build is broken in Maven c.f. [Incremental Build](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Incremental+Builds)

That logic can be changed to check if the output directory exists and if yes, if the XSD have changed. I may file a bug if I find time.

Answer (score 0):

Are the files actually regenerated? I have the following:

```
[INFO] File [C:\Projects\workspace-juno\maven-jaxb2-plugin-project\tests\po\src\main\resources\purchaseorder.xsd] was changed since the last build.
[INFO] File [C:\Projects\workspace-juno\maven-jaxb2-plugin-project\tests\po\pom.xml] was changed since the last build.
[INFO] Checking up-to-date depends [[C:\Projects\workspace-juno\maven-jaxb2-plugin-project\tests\po\src\main\resources\purchaseorder.xsd, C:\Projects\workspace-juno\maven-jaxb2-plugin-project\tests\po\pom.xml]].
[INFO] Checking up-to-date produces [[C:\Projects\workspace-juno\maven-jaxb2-plugin-project\tests\po\target\generated-sources\xjc\generated\Items.java, C:\Projects\workspace-juno\maven-jaxb2-plugin-project\tests\po\target\generated-sources\xjc\generated\ObjectFactory.java, C:\Projects\workspace-juno\maven-jaxb2-plugin-project\tests\po\target\generated-sources\xjc\generated\PurchaseOrderType.java, C:\Projects\workspace-juno\maven-jaxb2-plugin-project\tests\po\target\generated-sources\xjc\generated\USAddress.java, C:\Projects\workspace-juno\maven-jaxb2-plugin-project\tests\po\target\generated-sources\xjc\META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode]].
[INFO] Depends timestamp [1.395.259.386.093], produces timestamp [1.395.259.394.765].
[INFO] Skipped XJC execution. Generated sources were up-to-date.
```

It seems that the provided `org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental.BuildContext` says that the file has changed. But when the plugin checks the timestamps specifically, it sees that files are up-to-date. I think the problem is just in the log message, it should read `may have been changed`.

Please file an issue [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN).

Comment: Sorry for time responding... files are also regenerated